# Search by an array of primary key values

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have an array of maybe 1000 objects with a property called ItemId. ItemId refers to a tables primary key.

How do I get the best performance selecting 1000 rows by primary key? What is best practice?

- Looping 1000 times in a C# loop, i.e. 1000 no of roundtrips to the database?
- One sql with an in-list containing 1000 items?
- Use EF and join the array of objects with the table.

Any better ideas?

Comment: You should probably test the options to be sure, but I would assume table valued parameter to be the best one.

Comment: Table valued parameter seems to be the best option in my implementation. Then I will limit the no of roundtrips to the database. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best performance is usually reached by limiting the number of queries. However, using `WHERE ... IN` can be slow as well, because a subquery in the `IN` clause will be executed for every line you loop through. This depends on your database engine.

You could (and should always) test performance by trying out all three approaches. Only when you compare the performance on your specific system you will really know. To find out why performance is as it is you can use `EXPLAIN` before a query, to see what is happening.

In your specific situation you might find (using performance tests) that adding a temporary table that contains your array and then joining might have the best low level performance. Using the entity framework should be comparable, but it depends on the implementation.